# Ubuntu 16.04 installation issues

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and tried to install Ubuntu restricted extras but in software centre it is not found. Also I have less option in additional driver submenu. Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is not shown in the Ubuntu Software Center, it could be because you have not updated your application database or repositories. Try using the following from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I'm not sure, but if you are on Ubuntu and go to this [page](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/) the Ubuntu Software Center should open, and show the package ready to install.
If you want to use a GUI application to install packages, you could use [Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/) which you can find in the Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure that your system is fully updated.

Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (also known to windows users as Windows key), and type `Update`.

Select Software Updater from the options and it will check for any updates needed. Proceed with installation by typing your password whenever necessary.

---

Ubuntu Restricted Extras through Ubuntu Software Center will install all media codecs plus java and flash plugins.

You can install it via *GUI* or via *Terminal*.

---

*GUI* method.

---

Open *Ubuntu Software Center* and from the menu bar select *Edit > Software Sources*.

You have to make sure that the *multiverse* repository is enabled in *Software & Updates*. If it is not checked, please check it.
[image: Xubuntu 16.04 Software & Updates]

Upon checking it, you will be asked for your password.

Authenticate by typing your password and selecting <kbd>Authenticate</kbd>.
[image: Authenticate]

Now select <kbd>Close</kbd> to leave the *Software & Updates* window.

You will get a pop-up stating that your information is out of date and that you have to reload your sources.

Select <kbd>Reload</kbd> and let it reload.
[image: Reload information about available software]

- Close the Software Center and open it again. 
  Search for
  `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and under *Ubuntu Restricted Extras*
  select <kbd>Install</kbd>.

or

- Click  -> <kbd>[Ubuntu Restricted Extras](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-restricted-extras) [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras]</kbd> (to auto-open Software Center and select <kbd>Install</kbd>)

---

*Terminal* method.

---

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Type `sudo apt-add-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Type your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (typing will not be visible)

Again <kbd>Enter</kbd> when asked so the procedure can continue.

Type `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` when the previous command finishes.

Type `y` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>to confirm the installation.

*If any windows appears in the terminal, you can navigate through options with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and select an option with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key.*

[ubuntu-restricted-extras](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-restricted-extras) is now installed.